# Virtual Printer that can add metadata

Tags: printing

I need a virtual printer that can save a document to a directory, collect metadata on that document, and then either call a REST web service or generate an XML metadata file.

Features:

1. Can add custom metadata
2. Can call REST web script or generate an additional XML metadata file
3. Compatible with Windows 7, Chrome 36, IE 9, and Office 2013.
4. If at all possible can be deployed as a network printer

I will be happy with an API<sup>1</sup> that I can use to build what I want but I also have some funds for a vendor solution as long as it includes enterprise service and support.

<sup>1</sup> An API would need to be Java or .NET.